# Update table based on a custom requirement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to write a query to update a table based on below:

Let's say we have below table

```
Name  |Account  |Currency |Balance |
Sahil |Account1 |USD      |40,000  |
Rohan |Account2 |USD      |30,000  |
Mohit |Account3 |USD      |20,000  |
Ronak |Account4 |USD      |10,000  |
John  |Account5 |EUR      |50,000  |
Ram   |Account6 |EUR      |40,000  |
```

I want to deduct a total of $90,000. Firstly, I will deduct only from accounts having currency as USD because the amount which I want to deduct is in USD. Secondly, the way i want to deduct is start from the account which has the highest amount.

In my example I start with `account1` and deduct 40,000 and so on and so forth. After deduction, as per the example, I should have exhaused amounts in all of the accounts except account4. The table after deduction will look like below:

```
Name  |Account  |Currency |Balance |
Sahil |Account1 |USD      |     0  |
Rohan |Account2 |USD      |     0  |
Mohit |Account3 |USD      |     0  |
Ronak |Account4 |USD      |10,000  |
John  |Account5 |EUR      |50,000  |
Ram   |Account6 |EUR      |40,000  |
```

Same goes for Euro.

Is it possible to write a generic query where currency is my key?

One option I see is to write a cursor and iterate over records filtered by the given currency ordered by amount in descending order.

Comment: This is a pain in SQL Server 2008.  Sure you are not using 2012?

Comment: Thank you Gordon for the edit and comment. I am using SQL server 2008.. But there should be a way to do it?

Comment: If you can, nearly always avoid a cursor. They can quickly become very evil to your systems.

Answer (score 2):

Good question. It would be a lot easier if you had access to `LEAD` or `LAG` functions, but those weren't added until SQL 2012.

My shot:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=4a233d6088d885940d800477077009ba

I skipped the setup. Look at the Fiddle to get that.

> ```
> /* First I declare the inputs that I'll be using. */
> DECLARE @deductAmt int = 90000 ;
> DECLARE @deductCurrency varchar(10) = 'USD' ;
>
> /* Then I create the first CTE to get the basic data and a row number for each row. */
> ; WITH cte1 AS (
>   SELECT t1.Name, t1.Account, t1.Currency, t1.Balance
>    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t1.Currency ORDER BY t1.Balance DESC ) AS rn
>   FROM t1
>   WHERE t1.Currency = @deductCurrency
> )
> /* 
>    Then I use the first CTE to set up the CROSS APPLY to emulate the LAG() 
>    function (runtot). I subtract the runtot value from the @deductAmt that 
>    you passed in and declared at the beginning. 
> */
> , cte2 AS (
>   SELECT *
>     , @deductAmt-runtot AS dedTot
>   FROM cte1
>   CROSS APPLY (
>     SELECT SUM(c2.Balance) runtot
>     FROM cte1 c2
>     WHERE cte1.Currency = c2.Currency
>       AND cte1.rn >= c2.rn
>   ) ca1
> )
> /* 
>     Now that I have all the data mashed in the CTEs, I just query the 2nd CTE.
>     I use the CASE to check if you've used up the @deductAmt.
> */
> SELECT cte2.Name, cte2.Account, cte2.Currency, cte2.Balance
>   , CASE WHEN cte2.dedTot >= 0 THEN 0 ELSE cte2.Balance END AS deductBalance
> FROM cte2
> ORDER BY cte2.Balance DESC ;
> ```

That gives us.

> ```
> Name  | Account   | Currency | Balance | deductBalance
> :---- | :-------- | :------- | ------: | ------------:
> Sahil | Account1  | USD      |   40000 |             0
> Rohan | Account2  | USD      |   30000 |             0
> Mohit | Account3  | USD      |   20000 |             0
> Mohit | Account99 | USD      |   20000 |         20000
> Ronak | Account4  | USD      |   10000 |         10000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=4a233d6088d885940d800477077009ba)*

**NOTE:** I added in an extra row for Mohit/Account99 in USD for 20000 to show how this can handle rows that might have the same Balance. In the test, I also added an extra row for Ronak/Account4 using EUR, so that you can see how this query will also not sort people with the same Name and Account but a different Currency. I don't know if that's an actual possibility with your data, but it can be accounted for.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would perform with your data, but I will say that a good index should knock out some of the choke points in this query's plan.

Comment: And _technically_ you could get rid of the second CTE and just combine that with the `SELECT`; skip a step. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=2cc3034a0c824ddbc2a08c1d5c4ac68b

Comment: DBFiddle shows both plans to be the same (at least in their engine), so it's probably a matter of aesthetics.

Comment: Thank you so much Shawn for taking out time to answer the question. Will try it and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the sum of all "previous" accounts ordered by `balance` with a correlated subquery. Add the current `balance` and use a `CASE ... END` to check, if this result is less than or equal to the value you want to subtract. If it is, the new balance will be `0` else it's the result minus the value to subtract. With the same subquery you can limit the `UPDATE` to those rows, where the sum is less than or equal to the value to subtract, so that accounts "to low" don't get affected. But don't add the current `balance` here to get that "one more", that makes the boundary.

```
UPDATE elbat
       SET balance = CASE
                       WHEN coalesce((SELECT sum(t2.balance)
                                             FROM elbat t2
                                             WHERE t2.currency = elbat.currency
                                                   AND (t2.balance > elbat.balance
                                                         OR t2.balance = elbat.balance
                                                            AND t2.%%physloc%% > elbat.%%physloc%%)),
                                     0) + balance <= 90000 THEN
                         0
                       ELSE
                         coalesce((SELECT sum(t2.balance)
                                          FROM elbat t2
                                          WHERE t2.currency = elbat.currency
                                                AND (t2.balance > elbat.balance
                                                      OR t2.balance = elbat.balance
                                                         AND t2.%%physloc%% > elbat.%%physloc%%)),
                                  0) + balance - 90000
                     END
       FROM elbat
       WHERE currency = 'USD'
             AND coalesce((SELECT sum(t2.balance)
                           FROM elbat t2
                           WHERE t2.currency = elbat.currency
                                 AND (t2.balance > elbat.balance
                                       OR t2.balance = elbat.balance
                                          AND t2.%%physloc%% > elbat.%%physloc%%)),
                          0) <= 90000;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=87068690585e4c68886ae95e7cc4ee1a)

To handle accounts with the same balance a second criteria needs to be used. You didn't tell if there was a unique column in the table. I used the undocumented `%%physloc%%` pseudo column as a surrogate. It describes the physical location of a row. This seems to work but might be dangerous. Because it is not documented I cannot say if it might be affected whilst the execution of the `UPDATE` screwing things up. If possible you should replace it with a column unique in the table.

Comment: Thank you so much sticky bit for taking out time to answer the question. Will try it and get back to you. Thank you for your edit too..

Answer (score 0):

You need a cumulative sum, which is more painful than necessary in SQL Server 2008.  The rest is just an update and some arithmetic.  The logic looks something like this:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             (select sum(t2.balance)
              from t t2
              where (t.currency = 'USD' and t2.currency = 'USD' and t2.balance <= t.balance) or
                    (t.currency = 'EUR' and t2.currency = 'USD') or
                    (t.currency = 'EUR' and t2.currency = 'EUR' and t2.balance <= t.balance)
             ) as running_balance
      from t
     )
update toupdate 
    set balance = (case when running_balance < 40000 then 0
                        else running_balance - 40000
                   end)
    where running_balance - balance < 40000;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon for your answer. It would be great if you could just explain your query. N my table could have multiple currencies. Also in my actual table the key would be a combination of two columns and those columns might have random values too, so I cannot hard code. And also will this help me in starting with account having highest balance first. And the deduction happens in descending order of account balance.